# Grunt UseminPrepare Not Generating Configuration

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to use `grunt-usemin` to concatenate, minify, and remove unused optimized references from my project. I have set up the `build` blocks in my `index.html` file as so:

**Index.html**

```
<!-- build:js js/optimized.js-->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/config.js"></script>
<script src="app/config.exceptionHandler.js"></script>
<script src="app/config.route.js"></script>
<script src="app/common/common.js"></script>
<script src="app/common/bootstrap/bootstrap.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller1/controller1.js"></script>
<script src="app/services/service.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and my `gruntfile.js` looks like:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    useminPrepare: {
        html: 'index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '/dist'
        }
    },

    usemin: {
        options: {
            dirs: ['dist/index.html']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');

grunt.registerTask('testtask', ['useminPrepare', 'concat', 'uglify', 'usemin']);
};
```

However, `usemin` never actually generates the `concat` or `uglify` methods in my `gruntfile.js`. Instead, when trying to run

```
grunt.registerTask('newtask', ['useminPrepare', 'concat', 'uglify', 'usemin']);
```

I get an error stating that "No "concat" targets found".

My `gruntfile.js` and `index.html` are both in the root directory. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Running with `--verbose`**

```
Running tasks: useminPrepare

Running "useminPrepare" task

Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Verifying property useminPrepare.html exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> html
Options: dest="/dist"
Going through  to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks

Configuration is now:

  concat:
  undefined

  uglify:
  undefined

  cssmin:
  undefined
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire Gruntfile.js?

Comment: @LeonardoManrique Updated my original post to include full gruntfile

Comment: Running grunt with the verbose flag (`--verbose`) is usually helpful in debugging things like this. What's the output of running the task with the verbose flag?

Comment: @steveax Edited original to include `--verbose`.

Comment: So usemin prepare is not finding any blocks to process. What does the entire file/folder structure look like (`tree` is your friend here)

Answer (score 1):

Like spamguy say:
This error occur is because you write your html file path wrong.

as common it's:

```
useminPrepare: {
   html: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
   options: {
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
   }
}
```

please make sure usemin can find your index.html file by your html config.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html reference inside useminPrepare is missing `client/`:

```
useminPrepare: {
    html: 'client/index.html',
    options: {
        dest: '/dist'
    }
}
```

I compared against a project I'm working on that appears to have used the same yeoman generator.